# How to scan a symbol from the screen in C++ or Java?

Tags: java, c++

I want to create a program which must be able to scan symbols from the screen. More precisely I am thinking of a program which reads the cards from the tables in some Poker Software.

Now my question is how would I go about implementing this. Is this doable in Java or C++ or would I use some scripting language for this purpose? And how should I think about the scanning routine? How can the cards be read? Both the symbol and the number of the card must be registered somehow. What method should I use for this?

Hope I can get some good suggestions so I know how I could get started.

Comment: You can always capture the screen using either language and use an OCR library to determine the letters and some others to determine color (not sure about the symbols).

Comment: http://www.codingthewheel.com/archives/how-i-built-a-working-online-poker-bot-7/ is an interesting read - not exactly what you're asking though

Comment: [Java Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) is an option to capture the screen.

Comment: OCR is not a simple project and there may be a better way to do it. Does your poker software have a text window or log with the table activity? Text is much easier to parse!

Comment: Thanks for good suggestions and helpful links. Yes, I noticed the chat window contains all the events in the game - For example "Dealing Hole Cards (6h 2d)". I think I can get some useful tips form the link Mike Vine posted. I need to make a program which can activate the correct poker software window and locate the textbox and parse it.